# how to create new Entity using existing entity in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

We Have a very Nested Object for example

```
Class A {
  Set<B>
  Set<C>
  Set<D>
}
Class B{
  Set<P>
}
Class P {
  Set<X>
}
```

Now my requirement is to create duplicate object .

And Since we Don't want to touch existing entity so we need to create complete object.

Is hibernate gives any way to create complete object other than manually iterating each object and make Ids Null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I got your Problem. Why not create a new instance in Java and persist it like this (assuming you have created or injected an entitymanager):

```
@Inject EntityManager entityManager; 
....
A a = new A();
a.setFieldx(y);  // etc for all fields you want to set
....
entityManager.persist(a);
```

Comment: if i set entity id null and persist it will do, But i don't want that as it is very very complex object . I want a better option but thanks for giving your time.

Comment: I would not manipulate entity IDs the way you are doing it. You should create a new instance of the object and then you could use Apache BeanUtils -> copyProperties if you have to copy a large amount of fields.

Comment: I am using dozer mapper for field mapping , But event then we have to copy the reference of parent object in list child objects. You understand for complex it object it is really tedious task.

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question as it might be helpful for somebody who still needs such a thing. We had a similar requirement as well and Jackson came to the rescue. Below is a simple example:

```
public class Test {

    static class A {
        String id;
        String text;
        B objectB;
        //Getters & Setters
    }

    static class B {
        String id;
        String text;
        //Getters & Setters
    }

    @JsonFilter("idFilter")
    class PropertyFilterMixIn {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(
            Object.class, PropertyFilterMixIn.class);

        String[] ignorableFieldNames = { "id" };
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter("idFilter",
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(
                    ignorableFieldNames));
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);

        final A a = new A();
        a.setId("10");
        a.setText("A-Obj");
        B b = new B();
        b.setText("B-Obj");
        b.setId("12");
        a.setObjectB(b);

        final String string = writer.writeValueAsString(a);
        final A readValue = mapper.readValue(string, A.class);
        System.out.println(readValue);
    }
}
```

One thing that needs be considered is if the entities are bi-directional, then it can result in stackoverflow exception in JSON marshalling/unmarshalling. So use appropriate annotations on entities to get around that problem.